# my terminal is still running after my tkinter window has closed and i cant use CTRL+C on it

Tags: python, tkinter

its just a tkinter program that when i click on the X button the terminal stays busy
i cant use CTRL+C and i have to close the terminal manually
this is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def collatz(n):
    # Function to calculate the Collatz sequence
    sequence = [n]
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        else:
            n = 3 * n + 1
        sequence.append(n)
    return sequence


def show_collatz_graph():
    if hasattr(root, 'collatz_plot'):
        if isinstance(root.collatz_plot, FigureCanvasTkAgg):
            root.collatz_plot.get_tk_widget().destroy()
        else:
            root.collatz_plot.destroy()

    try:
        n = int(var.get())
        sequence = collatz(n)

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(sequence, color='white')
        for spine in ax.spines.values():
            spine.set_color('white')
        ax.set_facecolor("#36393e")
        fig.set_facecolor("#36393e")

        ax.xaxis.label.set_color('white')
        ax.yaxis.label.set_color('white')
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='white')
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().config(bg='#36393e')

        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        root.collatz_plot = canvas
    except ValueError:
        canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='#36393e', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        root.update()

        canvas_width = canvas.winfo_width()
        canvas_height = canvas.winfo_height()

        canvas.create_text(canvas_width/2, canvas_height/2,
         text="Why are you entering a word dude?\nLike what did I do to you? Why do I deserve this?",
          fill='white', anchor="center",font=("TkDefaultFont", 30))

        root.collatz_plot = canvas

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('900x900')
root.config(bg="#36393e")
root.title('Collatz Grapher')

var = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, font='arial', textvariable=var)

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Calculate Collatz', font='arial', bg='#36393e', fg='white', activebackground='#2f3136', activeforeground='white', command=show_collatz_graph)
btn.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,pady=20)
entry.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)


root.mainloop()
```

i tried closing the program using the X button but the terminal stayed open
i dont know why i tried using sys to kill the program when the mainloop stopps running and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

bind event to root

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda:on_closing_window())

def on_closing_window():
    root.destroy()
    sys.exit()
```

you can also bind specific keys to trigger the function.

Comment: hi i didnt really understand what you meant by that can you maybe show me an example

Comment: I dont know if thats will fix your problem, just an idea.

With root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda:on_closing_window()) you 'bind' the on_closing_window function to the 'X'. If you now close the Window the function will be executed and close your program.

How / where you run the program ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).